# qt button can not click when add from code

Tags: c++, qt

I add a button from my code and not from GUI . There is no error appear when compile ,but the button cannot click. here is code:

//mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QString>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void OnMsgSignal(const QString& tep2);
    void testForSocket();
    ~MainWindow();
    void readDataF();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString dataForTime;
    QPushButton *pushForTime;
};
```

//mainwidow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    pushForTime=new QPushButton(this);
    pushForTime->setText("点击获取时间");
    pushForTime->setGeometry(20,20,80,20);
    pushForTime->setEnabled(true);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

i add singal and slots to test it,but it failure.So i didnt add code for easy to read.
Thank you for your reading.

Comment: You probably want to do `ui->setupUi(this);` before you add your button and put the button into the layout of the MainWindow. Also how do you know it does not click since you have no signal / slot connection for the button.

Comment: i add singal and slots to test it,but it failure.So i didnt add code for easy to read.And if the button can click ,it also can appear clicked and no click effect when i click,but it just a button here and cannt click.

Comment: Please provide your code with signals and slots so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it in a wrong order.

First you add one big push button to your `QMainWindow` and then you re-init `QMainWindow`' GUI with UI-form by calling `ui->setupUi(this)`, it replaces your existing button with interface element from your UI file.

Try to add this extra button, to layout that exists in UI-form. For example:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
pushForTime=new QPushButton(this);
ui->mLayout->addWidget(pushForTime);
```

so it will be added to gui elements initialized from your UI-form.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is probably under some other widget (most likely the `QMainWindow`'s central widget). Call `ui->setupUi(this);` first in your constructor, before you initialize your button. This should fix it. You should still add the button to a layout though. Now I don't know if you've set a layout in your designer, but if you haven't, then set a layout to your mainwindow's central widget:

```
centralWidget()->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
```

After this just create your button like you do and add it to the layout:

```
centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(pushForTime);
```